# How to create offline database to be used with c++

Tags: c++

I saw already some questions with similar topic but my one is more of a beginner question.

I have already some experience with C++ and Microsoft Access but never came across how to actualy create or (if its not possible) than how to use an offline database similar to Access.
For example:

MS Access has its own tables etc... so I am about to build a program that will need offline database.

I think that to use simple txt files would not be the right way... What is my next option? Is there a way how all other programmers do it? Or would I just have to use one of the database providers like MySQL?

Comment: This is unclear ... are you looking for an embedded database for c++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096884/good-embedded-database-for-qt

Answer (score 7):

I think some people use SQLite for this purpose.  I don't know that much about it, but you can learn more here:

http://www.sqlite.org/about.html

Comment: Sqlite gets my vote. I'm currently working on a C++ wrapper around it (integrating Boost.Serialization) to implement a poor-man's NoSQL document storage library. It works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Microsoft stack, then you may want to give a try to [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx).

Alternatively, you may want to use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/index.html); it is not so integrated in the Microsoft ecosystem, but it is Open Source, and is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ODBC driver and link it with your database source file. Just read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca6axakh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

After setup your source use odbc api in your c++ code in order to make your queries. Also you can try to use ORM solutions in order to access your database.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software

Answer (score 0):

+1 for sqlite

If you're not *actually* interested in doing SQL-like queries, you could look at

- Serialization (e.g. [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html))
- [Boost Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) (focuses on structured config data, AFAICT)
- [LevelDB](http://code.google.com/p/leveldb/) (highperformance key-value store by google)

Cf. also hints on memory-mapping standard containers here:

[LevelDB vs. std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804692/leveldb-vs-stdmap/7805609#7805609)

Comment: Oh so many tips OK thaks guys for that looks like the Sqlite looks like the best option. Thanks